# Function with multiple template specifiers

Tags: c++

I do not understand the template defined below, can somebody help me decode it?

```
template <typename Impl>
template <typename datadec, typename T>
inline datadec<Impl>::codec(const T& value)
{
    return codec<datadec>(Master::char_data(value), Master::size(value));
}
```

Comment: This is the definition of the template member codec of template class datadec. Maybe it could help: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.mem#1

Comment: can you provide more context. I'm not able to reproduce this strange construction so it properly compiles. Note `datadec` is at the same time: template parameter, template and class scope. Also this example is missing return type or `auto` keyword so this even more makes me suspicious if it is rely a valid piece of code.

Comment: Assuming that `datadec` is a class template this is not a valid code because the `datadec` template parameter shadows the class name. Please provide the definition of the `datadec` class.

Comment: @r3musn0x I think you're correct in mentioning this, if only to prevent any confusion. I've edited my answer in an attempt to rectify any such unease.

Answer (score 10):

First of all, in case this isn't clear, the snippet as given by the OP doesn't compile. In keeping with what I believe is the intention behind it, two minimal modifications are needed to make it compile:

```
template <typename Impl>
template <typename datadec, typename T>
inline auto ::datadec<Impl>::codec(const T& value)
{
    codec<datadec>(Master::char_data(value), Master::size(value));
}
```

**To answer the question, let's go over this line by line:**

So, the `datadec` **class template** takes the single template argument `typename Impl`. Hence the first line:

```
template <typename Impl>
```

Now, the next two lines:

```
template <typename datadec, typename T>
inline auto ::datadec<Impl>::codec(const T& value)
```

constitute a definition for a **member function template** `codec()` of this class template `datadec` **(so it's a [member function template of a class template](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.mem#1))**. This function template itself takes two template arguments: `typename datadec` and `typename T`. Note that the first template argument here is of the same name as the class template itself -- `datadec`.

Notice: In the OP there was a return value type missing from this function declaration.

Next we see what's inside the member function definition:

```
{
    return codec<datadec>(Master::char_data(value), Master::size(value));
}
```

there's a call to a different `codec()` that is explicitly being used with a template argument that gets the `datadec` template parameter passed from the outside and takes two non-template arguments: `Master::char_data(value)` and `Master::size(value)`.

**Edit:** In an attempt to shed light on the "dual role" of the `datadec` name in this snippet -- as it seems to raise some eyebrows that this argument (taken by the member function template) is of the same name as the class template itself, as noted above: Without being provided more context by the OP, let's imagine, from a design perspective, that the class template `datadec` represents some *data decoder* and that `codec()` returns some [*codec*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec) related data. Then one reasonable explanation for these templated declarations to be as they are is that `codec()` needs to know what type of *data decoder* it needs to use for its return value -- as in, **you could specialize the two argument version of `codec()` for different types of `datadec`.**

Comment: can you provide working example? I don't get it why `datadec` at the same time is template parameter and class template name. What is the gain? Can compiler understand that? When I'm trying replicate this compiler complains on template definition, before I even try instantiate template. Missing return type makes question even more fishy.

Comment: @MarekR I added an edit to the answer to filling your request. Let me know your feedback, thanks.